# How to get the number/count/total of tags/badges/something from the API?

Tags: support, api, tags

I see we can [fetch tags via the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags?order=desc&sort=rank&site=stackoverflow), which works fine
but, sadly, there doesn't seem to be a way to get the count of all possible tags.

Currently [the Stack Overflow *Tags* page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) shows 36 tags per page with pagination up to page 1426, which means there are up to 51336 tags.

Does the API have any such feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was not originally clear if you wanted [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) or [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges), but the answer is the same...

To just get totals, use [the `total` filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters).
For example, **for badges**: [/badges?site=stackoverflow&filter=total](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/badges?site=stackoverflow&filter=total), which currently returns:

```
{"total":6363}
```

**For tags**: [/tags?site=stackoverflow&filter=total](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags?site=stackoverflow&filter=total), which currently returns:

```
{"total":48667}
```

#### WARNING:

In practice, the `total` filter is dangerous, because it masks errors, warnings and `backoff` intervals.
So, in practice use `!w-*Ytm8YGWVl9..xoC` instead of `total`, per: [My filter is not returning any results. How to create a minimal filter?](https://stackapps.com/questions/7829/my-filter-is-not-returning-any-results-how-to-create-a-minimal-filter).

---

If you want both the badges/tags *and* the total, you can set a custom filter, or just count the members of the `items` array as you page through them.  The latter option is less expensive in the API and thus less likely to get you [`backoff` warnings](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper).

Note that you can set the pagesize up to 100.  See [the doc page for tags](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags#pagesize=100&site=stackoverflow), for example.

---

---

**IMPORTANT:** [The *Tags* page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) also shows [synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-synonyms/info) and also a great many tags that have zero questions.
The API /tags route , however, returns neither of these, as best as I can tell<sup>‡</sup>. (3 or 4 very recently orphaned tags being the exception).  So the totals will not match up.

---

<sup>‡</sup><sub>EG, currently [Stack Apps only has 7 synonyms](https://stackapps.com/tags/synonyms).  Confirmed that none of those show in [the /tags route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags#pagesize=100&order=asc&sort=name&filter=default&site=stackapps&run=true), but all show on [the Tags pages](https://stackapps.com/tags).  Likewise, the only [zero count tag in the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags#pagesize=100&order=asc&sort=popular&filter=default&site=stackapps&run=true) is currently the *featured* tag, which is moderator only.</sub>